# Refactoring Java code to make it reusable

Tags: java, refactoring

I recently created a simple method that takes a HashMap and LinkedList as arguments. It iterates through the HashMap, find any two entries that follows these rules:

1. Sum of keys of this entries must be divisible by 100
2. Sum of keys must be less than 1000
3. If the entry with the same value appears more than once the case should be skipped

Pairs that follows these rules are added to the LinkedList. It looks like this:

```
private static void compare2(HashMap<Integer,String> values,List<String>results){
    if (values.size()>1) {
        for(HashMap.Entry<Integer,String> entry1:values.entrySet()){
            for (HashMap.Entry<Integer,String> entry2:values.entrySet()){
                if (entry1.getValue().equals(entry2.getValue()))continue;
                if ((entry1.getKey() + entry2.getKey())%100 == 0 && (entry1.getKey() + entry2.getKey())<1000){
                    results.add(entry1.getKey() + "+" + entry2.getKey() + "=" + entry1.getKey() + entry2.getKey());
                    results.add(entry1.getValue());
                    results.add(entry2.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to create similar method that finds 3 entries that follows the same rules. Problem is that I would like to reuse existing code instead of copy/pasting this and modyfiyng, and I can't seem to find a way to do that. I don't mind if I need to change my method as long as the result is the same.

Comment: Implement it for `n`(a parameter) instead of 2 or 3.

Comment: I don't see a way around adding more loops.  But even your current code has a problem.  If two entries have the same value, you are skipping over that pair of entries, even if they be different.  This is incorrect.

Comment: It works as it suppose to, I forgot to mention that the values are unique for each entry and it should skip the pair if values are equal.

Comment: @Oleg That is what I am trying to achieve but I can't figure how. If you could help me with that I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the amount of numbers a parameter: N.

You could stay using for loops, but an alternative example approach could be to refactor your method with lambda's and streams as follows:

```
List<List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>> compareN(HashMap<Integer, String> map, int n) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
              .map(entry -> listOfNAccompanyingEntriesThatSatisfyTheConditions(entry, emptyList(), map, n - 1))
              .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
              .collect(toList());
}
```

Where the method `listOfNAccompanyingEntriesThatSatisfyTheConditions` is a recursive method:

```
private List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>>
                listOfNAccompanyingEntriesThatSatisfyTheConditions(Map.Entry<Integer, String> newEntry,
                                                                   List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> selectedEntries,
                                                                   HashMap<Integer, String> originalMap,
                                                                   int n) {

        List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> newSelectedEntries = join(newEntry, selectedEntries);

        if (n == 0) return satisifiesCondition(newSelectedEntries) ? selectedEntries : emptyList();

        return originalMap.entrySet().stream()
                          .filter(entry -> !selectedEntries.contains(entry) && !entry.equals(newEntry))
                          .map(entry -> listOfNAccompanyingEntriesThatSatisfyTheConditions(entry, newSelectedEntries, originalMap, n - 1))
                          .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                          .collect(toList());
    }
```

For every *n*, the method takes another shot at the original full list to accumulate a sublist that might fulfil the requirements. If the amount of numbers is reached (n==0), the recursion stops and the stop condition is verified:

```
private static boolean satisifiesCondition(List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entries) {
    int sum = sumOfTheKeysFrom(entries);
    return sum % 100 == 0 && sum < 1000;
}
```

However, this approach is really an exact translation of your implementation and has still the same couple of issues. For example, if you run it for

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>() {{
        put(1, "fred");
        put(2, "anja");
        put(24, "tom");
        put(45, "eddy");
        put(22, "lenny");
        put(77, "tommy");
        put(55, "henry");
        put(43, "alfred");
    }};
```

You will yield double results and results with the same entry twice, such as:

> [1=fred, 22=lenny, 1=fred, 77=tommy] [2=anja, 55=henry, 2=anja,
>   43=alfred]

These are however easily solved by some small tweaks.

If you are not familiar with streams, lambda's or recursion, I'd suggest you implement the same with the imperative approach. Also be aware I did not care about performance in my example code, as I perceived this question as some kind of exercise.

Comment: That is exactly what I was counting for. This is not an exercise, however it is for home use and the database will be really small so the performance would not be very important.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static void check( final List<String> results,
                           final Map.Entry<Integer, String>... vals )
{
    int sum = 0;
    for ( final Map.Entry<Integer, String> val : vals )
    {
        final Integer key = val.getKey();
        sum += null == key ? 0 : key;
    }
    if ( sum < 1000 && 0 == ( sum % 100 ) )
    {
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder( 200 );
        for ( final Map.Entry<Integer, String> val : vals )
        {
            result.append( " + " ).append( val.getKey() );
        }
        results.add( result.append( " = " ).append( sum ).substring( 3 ) );
        for ( final Map.Entry<Integer, String> val : vals )
        {
            results.add( val.getValue() );
        }
    }
}

private static void compare2( final HashMap<Integer, String> values,
                              final List<String> results )
{
    if ( values.size() > 1 )
    {
        for ( final HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry1 : values.entrySet() )
        {
            for ( final HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry2 : values.entrySet() )
            {
                if ( entry1 == entry2 )
                    continue;
                check( results, entry1, entry2 );
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void compare3( final HashMap<Integer, String> values,
                              final List<String> results )
{
    if ( values.size() > 2 )
    {
        for ( final HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry1 : values.entrySet() )
        {
            for ( final HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry2 : values.entrySet() )
            {
                for ( final HashMap.Entry<Integer, String> entry3 : values.entrySet() )
                {
                    if ( entry1 == entry2 || entry1 == entry3 || entry2 == entry3 )
                        continue;
                    check( results, entry1, entry2, entry3 );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to avoid beacause I wanted to be able to add the possibility to compare 4,5,6 etc. elements. I was able to figure as much but it is still bothersome, as every following method would be much longer and would require much more code. I was hoping that someone would be be able to help me refactor this method so it would be scalable.